# UI-router : $state.current.name shows empty

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

Sometimes state which i define is not render and shows blank page.
And at this time when i try to see from console which state is this, it shows like below.

state name shows empty, which is not defined in my app.

[image]

Anybody know about this issue please help me.

Answer (score 1):

I am guessing you see the full object in console because it gets filled later and the browser reacts..
Try to include your block with $state into a $timeout(). It's a trick to wait for the $digest cycle to be over before getting the value.

```
$timeout(function() { console.log($state.current.name); });
```

or

```
$rootScope.$on('$stateChangeSuccess',
 function(event, toState, toParams, fromState, fromParams) {
 var statename = toState.name
 console.log(statename)  })
```